# Install Java version 8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, java

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and need to install java version 8 (or 9).

I did: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

But when I check current version using `java -version`, the result is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's version 8 what were you expecting? Java 9 would be `1.9.0_xxx`, your in order!

Comment: I thought this is `1.8` version... I expected something like: `openjdk version "8.xx.xx"`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - I didn't knew that, Thank You

Comment: Nobody talk about the Solaris/SunOS version naming pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed OpenJDK correctly. Java 8 and Java 1.8 are one and the same thing. It is just a naming convention [as explained in this post on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Do-Java-1-8-and-Java-8-refer-to-the-same-thing).